# Can not change Jenkins String Parameter Variable

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have Jenkins String Parameter ${EMAIL_ID} where user can enter their email id. (say they entered `myid@gmai.com`

But in the middle of the process i would like to change it to some value that i specify in the configuration as below in `Execute Shell` .

```
EMAIL_ID='example@ex.com'
echo $EMAIL_ID
--returns example@ex.com
```

If I use this variable in next `Execute Shell` 
it returns `myid@gmai.com`

I need to print `example@ex.com`

Answer (score 12):

Each "**Execute Shell**" or any other build step initiates a new and separate environment. This new environment inherits a copy of actual environment variables and all build parameters that are defined for the job, but realize that they are **copies/inherited**.

You can change the value of an environment variable easily:

- param=new_value (in Unix)
- set param=new_value (in Windows)

However that change will be **local** to *that* instance of the "execute shell" step. You can see the change if you echo that variable within the same "execute shell" step, but in the next "execute shell", you get a new copy (with original value).

To preserve your changed variable between build steps (or between jobs for that matter), you need to save it during the first step, and load it during the next. Easiest is to output the value to a file:
`echo param=$param > temp.props`
And then read this file into the second "execute shell" step using [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) (note, you will need to configure *EnvInject* build step in between your 2 existing "execute shell" steps.

Comment: i am doing the similar way. i am storing data into database then calling it whereever required.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the Jenkins environment variable like this in your batch script: %EMAIL_ID%

Comment: You mean will this replace string parameter ? `%EMAIL_ID%='example@ex.com'`

Comment: My understanding is that in a windows batch file, %EMAIL_ID%='example@ex.com' should work.

Comment: I tried in Windows batch file execution ; it failed 
`$ cmd /c call /tmp/hudson68740159.bat
21:36:39 FATAL: command execution failed`

Comment: Windows syntax is `set param=value`, the `%param%` is used to retrieve/read the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree to Slav.

it's possible to handover variables also w.o. Plugin.
just do:

```
echo set ENV_VAR=%ENV_VAR%>env_vars.bat
```

and then load it in the other batch scripts with:

```
call env_var.bat
```