# Ho do I set and get environment variables in windows batch command of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, advanced-installer

Here in the pic, you can see I am calling an API via curl. This API returns string data. I need to store this response in the Jenkins env variable and access the env variable in the second pic. I have tried setting the variable as you can see but its not the way to do it
[image]

[image]

How do I set and get environment variables in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to defined a [parameterized build](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds), with `VERSION` as a parameter.

[image: https://www.baeldung.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/jenkins-parameterized-builds-enable-checkbox.jpg]

---

Or, alternative option, you could use [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/), to:

- inject variables after a SCM checkout
  [image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin@master/docs/images/f6ac7022302083d1e8359babf478bacc1c70f926.png]
- inject variables as a build step
  [image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin@master/docs/images/0e0feead5d341176a406f68395e6f9df8b09a390.png]

That second option allows you to have a static value (always the same form build to build) in your job.

Both options will allow you to reference `%VERSION%` in a Windows shell (bat) script step.

---

Regarding setting a variable in one step, try and test it first, using `set`

```
set VERSION="xxx"
```

In the second step:

```
echo VERSION is '%VERSION%'
```

It should not work since, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390256/6309), each step has its own environment.

In that case, the first step should write the value in a file, and the second step should read that file.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I have successfully injected the environment variable using the Environment Injector, the problem lies is it assumed the curl script as the string content and it didn't allow to execute the curl and set the response string to the variable..

Comment: @DavidSilwal OK. Then the command to use is set: see my edited answer for a quick test. Once this is working, I will check `curl`

Comment: Thank you again for your quick answer, I just followed your step, and the version seems to set the empty value. I have just pasted my curl script, Could you please have a look into it?                                                                                 
 set VERSION = "curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"Link\": \"https://localhost\",\"Env\": 0,\"Software\": 0}" https:/localhost/api/jenkins/build"

Comment: @DavidSilwal I ùeant, test it *without* `curl` first. Simple step: one command. `set "VERSION=xxx"`, then see if VERSION is empty in the next.

Comment: @DavidSilwal OK. See my edit and its associated link. Using a file seems a good workaround.

Comment: let me give it a quick try using a file, It would very nice if we could do in this way