# What shells/command line tools does Jenkins have available on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, jenkins, sh

I note two different build steps: "Execute shell" and "Execute Windows batch command". The latter uses the windows shell, which of course is terrible... but what shell does the former use? I notice it is bash-like, though escaping has some weird properties (e.g. `$ENVVAR` wraps it in single quotes).

Also what tools are available? I notice that `tar` is available, for example, even though I never installed it on that machine. `which tar` reveals `/usr/bin/tar`, while `which zip` reveals "No zip in (`/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/bin:/ ... windows paths ...`)"... but where are these directories/what environment is the shell running in?

Searching `*.exe` in the Jenkins folder revealed neither an `sh.exe` nor a `tar.exe` so I'm not sure where these are coming from.

Specifically, a pointer to documentation for this would be appreciated - I haven't been able to find any yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [one thread on Jenkins Users](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/jenkins-release-plugin-what-is-the-difference-between-shell-and-batch-td3668178.html) that discusses this exact question.

In brief:

- Shell execute uses `sh`
- Batch uses `cmd`

If MinGW is installed Shell execute may be used.

---

From the Source:

- [BatchFile.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/e2dccc35572b64f5e602a6b1b3efb517c578872c/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/BatchFile.java)
- [Shell.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/e2dccc35572b64f5e602a6b1b3efb517c578872c/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/Shell.java)

that both derive from

- [CommandInterpreter.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/e2dccc35572b64f5e602a6b1b3efb517c578872c/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/CommandInterpreter.java)

Shell execute tries to run `sh` on Windows and `/bin/sh` on non-Windows (the distinction is actually done using the systems path separator). This may be changed using a shebang (see `Shell.buildCommandLine`)

Environment variables seem to be fetched from the Build itself (whatever that is) and then enriched by the current build variables, the server's URL, the current workspace, etc. This is quite intricate to discern from looking at the code itself. I've found [other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991863/can-not-change-jenkins-string-parameter-variable/22389389#22389389) that address the environment issue.