# I want to build multiple .net Solutions in Jenkins using MSBuild plugin

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I need to build more than 300 .net solution using MSbuild plugin in Jenkins. Please suggest a easy way to build all the solutions using MSbuild plugin.

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: @Manas you can create the single bat file to build all your solution and set the environment variable for your .net solution by executing the first command _`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`_ in your bat file, as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389389/3511167). In your case _`vcvars64.bat`_ path might be different. or you can use [MSBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin)